# i want replace output to text

Tags: awk, stdout, stdin, slackware, slackbuilds

i have below Code .

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#general", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #general and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

this command send `This is posted to #general and comes from a bot named webhookbot` to `Slack Channel` , now i want replace This with with output of

```
wc -l ips.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

i want this :

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#general", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "OUTPUT OF wc -l command , like number 154", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: What does `'payload...text": '"$(wc -l ips.txt | awk '{print $1}')"', "icon_emoj...}'` give you? You see: `$(command)` will give you the result of the command, but you need to do it outside of hard quotes.

Comment: Could you update the title of this Q to something that's specific and related to the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={'channel': '#general', 'username': 'webhookbot', 'text': \"$(wc -l ips.txt | awk '{print $1}')\", 'icon_emoji': ':ghost:'}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use backticks forcommand expansion:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#general", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "`wc -l ips.txt | awk '{print $1}'`", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Backquotes are not special within single quotes. Also, that first single quote after `awk ` is a closing quote, leaving `{print $1}` unquoted and preventing awk from seeing it as a single parameter (among other issues).